# Length of wire required for solenoid to produce desired magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

In a question:

> To construct a solenoid, you wrap insulated wire uniformly around a plastic tube 12cm in diameter and 50cm in length. You would like a 2.2 A current to produce a 2.6 kG magnetic field inside your solenoid.
>
> What is the total length of wire you will need to meet these specifications?

In the provided answer:

$$NC = nL C = (\frac{B}{\mu_0 I}) L (\pi d)$$

Where:

- $N$ is total number of turns
- $n$ is number of loops
- $C$ is circumference

But I dont understand why is there an $L$

---

I did it by:

$$B = \mu_0 n I$$

Then length of wire needed is just $nC$ whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$n$ in this case isn't the number of loops, it's the number of loops *per unit length*. This is why you have to multiply it by $L$ to get $N$.

Comment: True. Our professor stressed on this point a lot, so that we wouldn't make a mistake. :)